# how to set Document Types for QTKit in XCode 4?

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, quicktime, qtkit

I hope you can help me with my little problem here.

I'm just starting with Cocoa and XCode 4 and I'm working myself through a bunch of tutorials.
I have one tutorial off the Apple site called "QTKit Application Tutorial"
( it can be found here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationTutorial/BuildingaSimpleMediaPlayerApplication/BuildingaSimpleMediaPlayerApplication.html )

The problem is that this tut covers XCode 3.2 and I can't find the according settings in XCode 4.
I have my QT Player and I need to tell it which formats and extensions it can open.

In XCode 3, this is done via a few params as described in the tut.
Can you guys maybe tell me where I can find these settings in XC 4?

any help is strongly appreciated,

best,

Flo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Project Navigator (the first tab) select your project. In the editor select your target and open the Info tab. Document Types is the next sections after Custom Target Properties.
[image]